# Banshee won't open

Tags: 11.10, banshee

**Hello, world.**

My computer turned off while banshee was updating my music library. Now I can't open it. The error says: "found a fatal error. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db` (`~` means your home folder).
If you don't see the `.config` folder inside your home folder, press `CTRL+H` to make hidden files visible, and press `CTRL+H` again to make them invisible again when you're done.

`~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db` is the SQLite database where Banshee stores your music library. When you remove it it will be created again when you start Banshee.

---

Source: http://banshee.fm/support/faq/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but you could try deleting the local configuration files for Banshee and trying again.

Open Nautilus and press CTRL+H to show hidden files and folders.  Browse to the folder .local and inside you will find a folder called share.  Open this folder and find the folder called banshee and delete it.  Then try reopening Banshee.

If that doesn't work you can try reinstalling the application by using the following terminal commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove banshee
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Again, I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I'll add that if you try opening Banshee from the Terminal it should spit out an error report. If you post that here in your question, perhaps someone who knows more than me can help you.

Comment: Don't forget to make a backup of ~/.local/share/banshee before you try the steps @shawn mentioned.
You can also try to run these commands without deleting ~/.local/share/banshee
`sudo apt-get remove banshee
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banshee`
If that doesn't work out, you can try Shawns solution.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. The answer provided by RobinJ worked fine.