# How do you remove Banshee's user-level configuration settings? (i.e. those stored in the /home/user folders)

Tags: banshee, uninstall, purge

I have problems with Banshee, and decided to remove it and re-install it, but I would like to make a complete re-installation. I used remove and purge, but still I would like to remove all user configurations left. I will appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: does this Q&A help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/86675/banshee-wont-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control+H to show hidden directories on Nautilus file browser; don't know where is banshee configuration files, maybe on .config or .gconf

Answer (score 0):

You can install `Synaptic` from `Ubuntu Software Center` and select "Complete Removal" when selecting Banshee for uninstalling.

Alternatively you can run:

```
apt-get --purge remove banshee
```

If this doesn't help you can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86675/banshee-wont-open).

Comment: After purge and remove, I finally used sudo nautilus, and use CTRL-H to show hidden files, then looked for banshee-1 directory inside .local, .cache, .config, and I don't remember which one else, then reinstalled and that seemed to work.